# How can you remove notification of new Messages chat features

Tags: updates, notification-icons

A few updates ago on my Samsung Galaxy S10 added new "chat features from Google" and a notification of this new feature was flagged with the standard "N" icon:

[image: screenshot showing "N" icon]

Clicking the N icon brings up the Messages Settings

[image: messages settings]

and clicking on "Chat settings" comes up with

[image: chat settings]

I click on **use without chat features** and annoyingly the new feature notification N icon stays there.

I now know about the potential new features I don't want so the N icon should be gone.

How do I get that removed without accepting the new chat features?

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade the application
Download any earlier version of the app from [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/messenger-google-inc/). Don't download any beta version.. use stable ones.

Comment: Wouldn't downloading and installing earlier versions introduce potential security flaws onto the phone?

Comment: You can check the changelog of the app if there is any security update but to be honest the earlier version of the app is safe too after all it's made by google. But if you're not happy with it then you can use any other messaging app (which i don't recommend) Tell if you're not satisfied by the answer, I'll delete it.